# Split a string into two parts in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, strsplit

Input strings are :

```
InputStr1 = 'this-is-a-boy-5';
InputStr2 = 'this23-is-a-boy-10';
InputStr3 = 'this-41';
```

Output should be :

```
Output1 = ['this-is-a-boy'] [5]
Output2 = ['this23-is-a-boy'] [10]
Output3 = ['this'] [41]
```

I want to split these strings into two parts such that I can separate the first string and last number from it. I have tried `strsplit()` but It didn't help.

Comment: What's your regex ? Also post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting on the `-` which appears before number from end of string.

**Regex:** `-(?=\d+$)`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=\d+$)` looks ahead if the number is at end of string. And matches the `-` before it. You can split on this.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS4kA4/1)**

Answer (score 5):

This should work (assuming there is number always in last)

```
data = 'this-is-a-boy-5'
toks = regexp(data, '(.*)-(\d+)$', 'tokens');
display(toks)
```

If you want to use `strsplit` you can use it as

```
toks = strsplit(data, '-(?=\d+$)', 'DelimiterType', 'RegularExpression');
display(toks)
```

Comment: Up vote for better use of regex than the accepted answer.